# Does the C++ 20 working draft include aliasing imported modules?

Tags: c++, c++-modules

Does the Modules TS include aliasing symbols of imported modules? I did some brief searching but didn't see anything that mentioned this.

Bad example in hindsight, but I'm curious if there's any c++ equivalent to ES201N's

```
import { MyThing as OtherThing } from "ThingModule"
```

Comment: Is there a known term for what you're asking about?  A Google search for `"c++" "type aliasing imported modules"` as of this moment returns zero results.  And perhaps you can add an explanation of what you think the effect of your example code would be.

Comment: That's basically what I'm looking for. C++ has type aliases e.g. using identifier = type;  Certain module systems for other languages allow you to alias your imports in the same statement, which is nice e.g. import foo as bar.  But again, my light googling didn't reveal anything pertaining to this and the c++ 20 draft.

Comment: So you're not talking about type aliasing but renaming imported symbols (which are not types)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "modules TS" includes support for `import std`, but nothing like `import std::cout`.  Also, `std::cout` is a value, not a type.  So you'll need to `import std` then do whatever you can do since C++11 to alias `std::cout`, e.g.:

```
import std;
auto& myCout = std::cout;
```

Edit: Later on  you edited the question.  The answer is still no, because you're asking to import specific things within a module, which the modules TS does not support.

Comment: I updated my question with a better example.  import std::cout isn't really what I intended to articulate. If you could revise your answer to reflect the edit, I'll accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: You've substantially altered your question, but I think my answer still applies.  You've now referenced "ES201N" which again is not a term which can be Googled, so I have no idea what that is.  I'm going to leave this answer alone for now, as I don't know what I'd change and I'm not really interested in chasing changing questions.

Comment: ES201N refers to any of the ES2015, ES2016, ES2017, ES6, ES7, ESN, whatever they're calling modern javascript these days. My question is true to my original intent.  I'm relatively new to c++ and typed languages in general, so apologies for my jargonal inaccuracies. This is why I came here to ask.

Comment: OK, I'd added a bit to my answer (which still boils down to "no").  I hope you'll understand that many C++ folks have no idea what ES201N refers to when Google doesn't know.  "ECMAScript" is understandable and Googleable.